# unable to setState on form submit-success event AMP

Tags: javascript, amp-html

when i am submitting a form on the submit-success event i am trying to submit another form but it results in an trust level error stating that the submit-success does not have the same level of trust to set the state.
I checked that amp-form submit event and setState event have same trust level as HIGH but didnt find the trust level for submit-success event

```
"submit-success" event with "low" trust is not allowed to invoke "amp.setState".
```

dummy example

```
<form id="f1" method="POST" xhr-action="dummyapi" on="submit-success:AMP.setState({dummy:true})">

<!--fields-->
</form>

<form id="f2" method="POST" xhr-action="dummyapi" on="submit-success:f1.submit">

<!--fields-->
</form>
```

the setState on submit of form f1 wont work

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, where's your code? Why can't you insert a simple valid AMP template? You probably expect someone to do everything for you, but this will not always happen.

---

I tried to do what you wrote and everything works for me, look:

```html
<!--
     This is the minimum valid AMP HTML document. Type away
     here and the AMP Validator will re-check your document on the fly.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ⚡>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="self.html" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1" />
  <style amp-boilerplate>
    body {
      -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
      animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    
    @-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    
    @-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    
    @-o-keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    
    @keyframes -amp-start {
      from {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      to {
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
  </style>
  <noscript>
    <style amp-boilerplate>
      body {
        -webkit-animation: none;
        -moz-animation: none;
        -ms-animation: none;
        animation: none;
      }
    </style>
  </noscript>
  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
  <script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>First form</h2>
  <form id="secondForm" method="post" target="_top" action-xhr="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/echo">
    <input type="hidden" value="hiddenValue">
    <div submit-success>Second form send successful!</div>
    <div submit-error>Second form send failed!</div>
  </form>

  <hr>

  <h2>Second form</h2>
  <form id="firstForm" method="post" target="_top" action-xhr="https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/api/verify-form-input-text-xhr" on="submit-success:secondForm.submit">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <div submit-success>First form send successful!</div>
    <div submit-error>First form send failed!</div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/wvGJvzJ?editors=1000

Comment: Thanks. I have missed few points. I have updated the problem. please let me know if there is a work around

Comment: @AshishSharma Well, I tried what you're talking about. I also get an error. I think it's impossible to do what you want. I suggest you write `AMP.setState({dummy:true})` for the first form to send. You can also ask in the official github repository AMP, attaching a link to this topic. I will think more about this problem, and if I find an answer, I will write later.